# Reading binary file but want to convert to text/string

Tags: python, excel, binary, hex

I am reading a binary file:

```
    file = open("TPSDisplay/Reader/radio_log.BIN","rb")
    lines = file.read(100)
    file.close()
```

When I run `print(lines)`, it prints the converted binary string, in this case it is:

`'\r\n01659963148.977->>(\x00\x00\x00\xa5v\xe6A\x0033\x0033\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd9\xfb\x00\x0c\x17\x90\x01M\x04\x00\x00\x00\x1d\xb3\x1c\xf6\x8ep\xf7N\xf6\x00\x00\r\n01659963148.977->>(\x00\x00\x00\xa5v\xe6A\x0033\x0033\x00\x00\x00'`

Now I want to split this string about the `\r`'s and do general string manipulation, but since `lines` is not a normal string object I cannot do so.

Note:
I think the hex represents an excel table as that is what is usually outputted with this binary file, if you have an idea on how to interpret the data following the long digit that would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: Your data almost certainly does not represent any kind of encoded string and, if that's the case, you'll never be able to convert it to a Python string. What do you know about the origin of the data?

Comment: @Stuart The data is actually run through a program and converted to an excel file, I assume the arrow denotes the container of a cell or a row of cells. So any help on interpreting that would be useful.

Comment: It seems strange that an Excel file would have a .BIN extension but, of course, that's quite possible. Have you tried opening it in Excel?

Comment: @Stuart I have it's unsupported, essentially the whole background is these measurements are taken from a sensor which is then run through a program which converts the hex into an excel file. I am trying to reverse engineer that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use

```
lines.decode("utf-8")
```

to convert the bytes to string and process it.  That said, binary files can not be converted to human-readable text.

Comment: I tried this but it fails to decode it due to an invalid start byte for ```0xa5```

Comment: You could try other encode str like utf-8 -sig or ansi?

Answer (score 0):

You can write `lines.decode(someEncoding)` where `someEncoding` is Windows/DOS codepage number as `str` or `unicode` (depending on your Python version). You can use any codepage you want.